# Validation for multiple checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple checkbox in each row:

```
<form id="CustomerNEmployeeForm">
<table>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>
            <div class="i-checks"><input id="checkboxCustom1" type="checkbox" name="[0].RightsCodes.OpenOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Open Orders</label></div>
            <div class="i-checks"><input id="checkboxCustom2" type="checkbox" name="[0].RightsCodes.ClosedOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Closed Orders</label></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td>
            <div class="i-checks"><input id="checkboxCustom1" type="checkbox" name="[1].RightsCodes.OpenOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Open Orders</label></div>
            <div class="i-checks"><input id="checkboxCustom2" type="checkbox" name="[1].RightsCodes.ClosedOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Closed Orders</label></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
 <button class="btncreateusers" id="createusersJS" type="button" onclick="CreateCustomerNEmployees(this);"> Create</button>
</form>
```

And Im trying validate checkbox where user checked at least one of checkbox in each row.

This my JavaScript so for , but still no luck:

```
<script>
    function CreateCustomerNEmployees(e) {

        var boxs = $(e).closest("tr").before();

        if (boxs.find('input[class=checkbox-template:checked]').val() == "") {

            alert("check at least one");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me! :)

Comment: The `button` doesn't appear to be in the table, so `closest()` isn't going to find a `tr`. Also note that if `:checked` doesn't find anything then `val()` will return `undefined`. While your code would still work, it's relying on type coercion, which is less than ideal. Once you've fixed the DOM traversal problem, I'd suggest using `.length === 0` instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry my button  appear in form and I just update HTML, would you please suggest a way , where i can archive this :)

Comment: Your checkboxes have duplicate id, change them to unique ones

Answer (score 0):

As @barbsan comment id's are unique.
As for your question, you can do it like that:

1. set variable for all the checkbox (with your code you can detect them with the class "checkbox-template".
2. Iterate all of them and put condition to check if at least one is checked or not.

Example with vanilla js:

```js
function CreateCustomerNEmployees() {
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-template');
  for (var i=0; i < box.length; i++) {
    if (box[i].checked) {return}
    else {alert('please check one checkbox'); return}
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="CustomerNEmployeeForm">
<table>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>
            <div class="i-checks"><input id="checkboxCustom1" type="checkbox" name="[0].RightsCodes.OpenOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Open Orders</label></div>
            <div class="i-checks"><input id="checkboxCustom2" type="checkbox" name="[0].RightsCodes.ClosedOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Closed Orders</label></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td>
            <div class="i-checks"><input id="checkboxCustom3" type="checkbox" name="[1].RightsCodes.OpenOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Open Orders</label></div>
            <div class="i-checks"><input id="checkboxCustom4" type="checkbox" name="[1].RightsCodes.ClosedOrders" value="true" class="checkbox-template"><label for="checkboxCustom1">Closed Orders</label></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
 <button class="btncreateusers" id="createusersJS" type="button" onclick="CreateCustomerNEmployees();"> Create</button>
</form>
```

Edit - If you have more forms on page and you are using the same class, you can check just the specific form like that:

```
<script>
function CreateCustomerNEmployees() {
var theForm = document.getElementById('CustomerNEmployeeForm');
  var box = theForm.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-template');
  for (var i=0; i < box.length; i++) {
    if (box[i].checked) {return}
    else {alert('please check one checkbox'); return}
  }
}
</script>
```

Hope that helps.